# Fenced code blocks don't close properly at the end of a post

Tags: bug, status-review, markdown, mathjax

The new feature, GitHub (tilde) code blocks, from [Implement ```-style (fenced) Markdown code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125148/216398) is a great addition, but there is a small bug which bizarrely only appears on Code Review & Code Review Meta. If a code block contains a blank line anywhere, *and* the closing ```` ``` ```` isn't followed by a newline, it will be taken as code rather than a closing fence.

The bug applies to both the previews of the posted content. It can be worked around easily enough by finishing the post with a newline but is unexpected. The source of the problem seems to be [due to MathJax](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9148#comment19367_9148).

This can result in accidental noise in any code block at the end of a post:

````
some code

more code but there was a blank line above
```
````

Comment: I think I'd consider that [tag:status-bydesign] pending "Word of God" from the implementing dev.

Comment: @Vogel612 the thing is that the same bug does not appear on the main meta site, nor on StackOverflow. So I'm thinking it's some interaction with bespoke CodeReview formatting. Also it only manifests if there's a blank line somewhere in the posted code. It's just too weirdly specific to be intentional.

Comment: I agree, this does seem like a bug.

Comment: Appears to be some weird interaction with MathJax. Wild...

Comment: Attempting to "bump" because this is still an issue: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/229448/1

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think "bump"ing like that just alerts the OP (in this case, me). If you really want to, you could edit your link into the question text, which will bump it to the front page. People might get annoyed though; voting is the usual way to show agreement. Presumably if it wasn't fixed last time, it won't be fixed now either.

Comment: @Dave Ya, I thought a comment would be sufficient to make the question considered "active", but I checked the active page and it wasn't there. And ya, the comment was ill-thought-out.

Comment: "_it will be taken as code_" - do you mean _it will be **formatted** as code_? _taken_ gives me images of Liam Neeson on the phone (even though I never saw the movie)...

Comment: @AdamLear could SE append a newline to the body of posts to fix this. A simple `if not post.body.endswith('\n'): post.body += '\n'`. Sure it's a monkey patch, but it's been a year...

Comment: This issue still persists. This was posted on April 13, 2019. It has been **583** days

Comment: This is still an issue.  I just fixed it on new questions like https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/275640/89257 -- at least the work around is easy.

Comment: as per https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1237/backticks-showing-in-fenced-code#comment4106_1237, this doesn't appear to be an issue any more. Can someone involved in the thread still repro it?

Comment: @JNat: [Here's one!](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283194/75307)

Comment: @JNat [Another example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/283294/revisions), see difference rev 1 and 2.

Comment: @JNat And [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/283309/revisions), between rev 1 and 2 again.

Comment: @JNat I don't know if it has been considered, but [adding an extra newline if the post ends on triple grave](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10789/52915) would be a relatively easy workaround. Probably good UX too.

Comment: The issue still seems present: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/283665/revisions